# How to display dynamic navigation bar from blade template

Tags: php, laravel, routes

I have a navigation bar stored in the database, and I have a Controller witch lists the navbar for my template file.

```
$navbar=/*Query*/
return view('inc.template')->with('nav',$navbar);
```

I have other pages where I want to use the template with the navigation bar of course, but when I extend the template  I get error message 'Undefined variable $nav'. I understand why I get this error message, because I don't returned the variable for the other page. So I need solution for this.. every idea is welcome!.

I have single product page, where I want to include the template with the navigation bar and also I will list the Single Product here.

I know I can  copy the query code and paste it to the single product controller, but I believe this is not a good solution (repeating myself).

Thanks in advance for your ideas!

Comment: Having a separate route for a view is not the way to do this. Look at blade layouts (something like `@include('navbar')` in your `layouts/master.blade.php`), or view composers, etc etc. https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/views#attaching-a-composer-to-multiple-views

Answer (score 1):

You need to check the View Composer which will help you do what you want : https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/views#view-composers (use the correct Laravel version).

In order to do this, you will need to create a new class that will be your view composer and then register it to the container of Laravel.

In your case, that would be something like this :

```php
<?php

namespace App\Http\View\Composers;
use Illuminate\View\View;

class NavbarComposer
{

    /**
     * Create a new navbar composer.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        // If you need to do something when instanciating this view composer
    }

    /**
     * Bind data to the view.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\View\View  $view
     * @return void
     */
    public function compose(View $view)
    {
        // here you can add as many variables that your navbar might need
        // first parameter is the name of the variable and second the value.

        $view->with('navbarData', []);
    }
}
```

To register your view composer you can then do something like this :

```php
 View::composer('profile', ProfileComposer::class);
```

Maybe take a tour to https://www.laracasts.com to learn the basics of Laravel because that's not how to use routes.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/27920647)

Comment: Thanks I wasn't aware of that and it makes totally sense. I'll edit my answer.

Answer (score 0):

The simple answer is: you just need to return everything that belongs to your **home.blade.php** in the index function of the **HomeController**. You should do something like this:

```
public function index(){

$navbar = "Your query to get navbar data";

return view('home',[
'navbar' => $navbar
]);

}
```

Then call the navbar data into your home.blade.php ( or into the actual navbar.blade.php  ) by using foreach.

**Note:** If you want to call the navbar in multiple views just call the navbar data from all the view returning functions as like index function.

**UPDATE**

To achieve that you can just do something as:

```
public function index(){

$navbar = "Your query to get navbar data";

 if(count($navbar) == 0){
   $navbar = "";
 }

$slider = "Your query to get slider data"; 

if(count($slider) == 0){
  $slider = "";
}

return view('home',[
'navbar' => $navbar,
'slider' => $slider,
]);
}
```

Comment: This will work, but it's a rough approach. If you have multiple functions in multiple controllers that are all returning a view that needs the navbar, each one will need `$navbar = ...;` and `['navbar' => $navbar]`. Code very quickly becomes not DRY (don't repeat yourself), and if you need to update it, you're updating X places instead of 1.

Comment: Thanks, your answer is okay, but I have to return slider data too. I know that I can return two or more arrays but  in my application there are situations when slider or navbar is not available, soo I want to return  navbar or slider if its available in the database, and that is the biggest problem. If I use IF condition to check if navbar or slider is setted than the controller will return just FIRST, and not second..

Comment: That's right it's lengthy. But it's not a rough way to achieve this actually . It's the basic way that makes the questioner's  idea clear about what is the appropriate way to use functions and routes. He may use a constructor function to make it done so easily but you should understand that the basic needs to be clear first.

Comment: @codemaster96 I can understand what you are asking for. But that becomes a different question. Since you have asked that in comment , the answer may not be clear. If you update your question then I may answer that too.

Comment: Good idea,  so at home page I have  just to check the navbar or slider variable size. Clearly the best answer so far, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I don't really understand your code, but I think this may help you:
If you want to get the variable in your non-yield blades, you can share your variable from controller's constructor, so don't need to add that in all methods. Just add this constructor method in your controller-class like this:

```
// ADD THIS >>>
public function __construct()
{
    View::share('data', 'example');
}
// <<<

// YOUR EXISTING METHOD >>>
public function index()
{
    return view('navbar');
}
// <<<
```

Now you can access $data variable in your blade, which are used in your appropriate page.

Don't forget to use this class in the top of controller's class:

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\View;
```